# Holomorphic Functions as complex charts

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Assume that $f$ is a holomorphic function at $p \in X$ ($X$ Riemann surface) and that $mult_p(F)=1$. Is it true that $f$ is a complex chart? And in general every holomorphic map from an open set of a Riemann surface $X$ having constant multiplicity one is a complex chart?

In order to answer to the first question, I use the normal form of f. So, there exists a neighborhood of $p$ for which $f$ assumes the form $z \mapsto z$. It is clearly continuous and invertible, but what can I say of the inverse map?

Concerning the second question, I think the answer is no. Can you provide a counterexample, please?

Comment: What do you mean by a "complex chart"? Do you mean a biholomorphic map from a Riemann surface to an open subset of the complex plane? If so, then "yes" for both questions. Bijective holmorphic maps between complex manifolds of the same dimension are, in fact, biholomorphic (this is true in higher dimensions as well).

Comment: A complex chart $(U,\phi)$ at $p$ is a pair constituted by an open neighborhood of $p$ and a homeomorphism from $U$ to an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Clearly, when I consider a function $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic  at $p$, I mean a function such that $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is holomorphic at $\phi(p)$ as a complex-valued function for any complex chart $(U,\phi)$ at $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open subset of a Riemann surface $X$ and $f: U\to {\mathbb C}$ an injective (aka one-to-one) holomorphic function. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism to its image. This is immediate from the property that nonconstant holomorphic functions (with connected domain) are open mappings.

Actually, one has more, namely, that $f: U\to f(U)\subset {\mathbb C}$ is a biholomorphic mapping, i.e. its inverse is also holomorphic. There are several ways to see this. One is to use the normal form of holomorphic functions (which, I think, you are familiar with):

Lemma. Let $h: D\to {\mathbb C}$ be a holomorphic function defined on an open subset $D$ in ${\mathbb C}$. Then for every $p\in D$ there exists a pair of biholomorphic (to their images) functions $\phi, \psi$ defined on neighborhoods $V$ and $W$ of $p$ and $f(p)$ respectively, such that 
$$
\psi\circ h \circ \phi^{-1}
$$
has the form $z\mapsto z^n$, where $n\in {\mathbb N}\cup \{0\}$.

This lemma (assuming $h(p)=0$) is proven by writing $h$ (near $p$) in the form $h(z)= (p-z)^n g(z)$, where $g$ is a nonvanishing holomorphic function near $p$. Then consider a branch of the $n$-th root of $h(z)$:
$$
h^{1/n}(z)= (p-z) (g(z))^{1/n}
$$
and observing that this holomorphic function has nonzero derivative at $p$.

Applying this lemma  in your situation and taking into account that your function $f$ is injective, we conclude that the number $n$ in this lemma equals to $1$ at every $p\in U$. Hence, $f$ restricts to a biholomorphic function on a neighborhood of every point $p\in U$. (Since your $f$, locally, is a composition of three biholomorphic functions.) Hence, $f^{-1}: f(U)\to U$ is holomorphic near each point $q\in f(U)$, hence, $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic.

Comment: The fact that I don't see is the following: by the normal local form theorem I have that $f$ can be locally described as the map $z \mapsto z$. In particular, since the complex charts are centered in $p$ and $\psi(p)$ respectively, I'm sending a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ into a disk centered at the origin. At $z=0$, the inverse map $\frac{1}{z}$ is not holomorphic. Where do I mistake?

Comment: @TheWanderer $1/z$ is not the inverse of the identity map. You are confusing the two notions of an inverse.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I was confusing myself with a stupid error of distraction. It's obvious, you're right!